# Create abstract class for unit test in spring boot without tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

I try to create abstract unit test class in Spring Boot. While I can a unit test following:

```java
@WebMvcTest(Rest.class)
class AbstractRestTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    void baseTest(String urlTemplate, String expectedValue) throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(urlTemplate);
        MvcResult results = mvc.perform(request).andReturn();

        assertEquals(expectedValue, results.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        baseTest(urlText, expected);
    }
}
```

But while I create an abstract class following, don't run the test:

```java
public class RestTests extends AbstractRestTest {
    
    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        baseTest(urlText, expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try moving @WebMvcTest(Rest.class) from AbstractRestTest to RestTests. That would mean, that RestTests will execute both @Test methods.

Comment: thank you, worked it. I want to ask one more question. Where is it appropriate to get the test data from? h2 db or application.yaml or else?